# Using hostname on Current machine

Tags: c++, c, hosts

I'm using sockets to connect and the client needs the hostname of the server. I'm running it all on the same machine and my hostname worked. The problem was that my hostname was REALLY long and I didn't want to spend all that time typing it out. So, What I did was I sudo su'd and did

```
hostname brandon
```

I then typed

```
hostname
```

it showed "brandon"

I then ran the program with brandon as the hostname and it said it couldn't resolve host.
Any help?
I even edited my hostname file in /etc/hostname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's `/etc/hosts` instead of `/etc/hostname`

You could add a line in /etc/hosts file to resolve the hostname lookup

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx      brandon
```

replace `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx` with the real ip address

Comment: how would you change your hostname using the hostname command line?

Comment: actually it depends on which linux OS you are using. could find something on internet about linux changing hostname ... but not just from command line, you need to modify a few files...